# Why does this expectation integrate to 1

Tags: probability, statistics

Let $p(y|\theta )$ be our likelihood, and $\hat{p}_{N}(y|\theta)$ be an unbiased estimator of our likelihood.  Let $z=\ln \hat{p}_{N}(y|\theta) - \ln p(y|\theta )$, and $g_{N}(z|\theta)$ be the density of $z$.  Since our estimator is unbiased, we have $\int e^{z} g_{N}(z|\theta)=1$.  Why?

Note: just in case someone thinks this is a homework problem, it isn't, as it is from page 04 here http://xxx.tau.ac.il/pdf/1503.08621v1.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\int e^{z} g_{N}(z|\theta) \mathrm{d}z
= \int \frac{p_{N}(\hat{y}|\theta)}{p(y|\theta)} g_{N}(z|\theta) \mathrm{d}z
= \mathbb{E}\left[\frac{p_{N}(\hat{y}|\theta)}{p(y|\theta)}\right]
= \frac{\mathbb{E}\left[p_{N}(\hat{y}|\theta)\right]}{p(y|\theta)}
= \frac{p(y|\theta)}{p(y|\theta)} = 1$$

Comment: Lol, so obvious once I see it.  Didn't see that we could factor out the denominator in the expectation.  Thanks.

Comment: The OP's notation involving a mysterious $\hat{y}$ makes the question almost unintelligible. The posted link makes it clear that *the expectation in question is with respect to all auxiliary random variables (say $X$) used by the estimator* $\hat{p}_{N}(y|\theta)$:

$$\mathbb{E}_X\left[\frac{\hat{p}_{N}(y|\theta)}{p(y|\theta)}\right] 
= \frac{\mathbb{E}_X\left[\hat{p}_{N}(y|\theta)\right]}{p(y|\theta)}
= \frac{p(y|\theta)}{p(y|\theta)} = 1.$$